# Problem with displaying data from api in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, api

In my app I am calling the iTunes api and when I log the response it is coming back with [object object]. I know it must be to do with the array structure of the api. I have a service being injected into a component as follows: BTW I have a proxy.conf.json file for the api.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  api: string = 'api';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.api)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  public results = [];

  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }
  private http: HttpClient
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getApi();
  }

  private getApi() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('JSON Response = ' + results);
    })
  }
}
```

**Api structure**

```
{ 
   "resultCount":50,
   "results":[ 
      { 
         "wrapperType":"track",
         "kind":"song",
         "artistId":271256
      },
   ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is correct, if you want to see it as a JSON, you need to use JSON.stringify

```
 this.service.getAll().subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('JSON Response = ' + JSON.stringify(results));
      data = results.results;
})
```

if you want to iterate over elements with ngFor use

```
 <li *ngFor="let dataObj of data">
      {{ dataObj.wrapperType}}
 </li>
```

Comment: What if I want to display the "WrapperType" for example?

Comment: Also the JSON.stringify just shows the json response, I want to log all the data as it comes back in JSON format

Comment: just access using dot operator

Comment: like results.wrapperType